Windows EC2 Inscance cannot access https page on specific port
I have an EC2 Intance running on Amazon AWS and it needs to do a GET Request to an URL in the 48080 port. Something like:
GET https://someurl.com:48080/someresource

When I put this URL on my personal browser it gets the expected result just fine, but from the browser in the EC2 Instance, I am getting the "This site can't be reached" error.
To solve the problem, I tried to open the 48080 port on the AWS Security group, creating a new inbound rule for any IP (0.0.0.0/0), accepting TPC connections and I disabled my Windows Firewall, but the error continues. My outbound rules are acepting all traffic.
I tried to disable "source/destination checks" as per this post: AWS EC2-Windows Server cannot access outside network, but it didn't work eighter.

Some websites block the IP address range of Amazon EC2 instances to prevent scraping. Can you access that website on normal 80/443?

I can't, it's only accessible through this port. But It could be that, because I can access from different devices, but not from the EC2 Intances I have. I was hoping its something on the security group, but I oppened the ports and it didn't work.
